# Best way to track maximal distance in a set of points?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math, data-structures

Assume that I have a collection of 2 dimensional points, and a way to determine the distance between them.  This collection is frequently modified, with additional points being added and existing points being removed.  At any given time, I need to know the maximal and minimal distances between the points, that is, the distance between the two points furthest apart, and the distance between the two points closest together.  is there a data structure or algorithm that lends itself particularly well to this task?  I would prefer not to have to recalculate the entire set of distances each time that the points change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically, you can do this efficiently by storing the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the points you have.

Whenever you add a new point, test to see if it lies in the interior of this [polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) or not. If so, the max distance is preserved. If not, then it may have changed.

Similarly, if you delete a point from the interior, the maximum distance (diameter) is preserved, so change nothing. However, if you delete a boundary point, then the convex hull must be recomputed.

If you are in 2 dimensions, then when you add or remove from the boundary, at most two sides of the polygon are affected. These should be easy to compute, depending on how you store the information (a sequence of line segments, for example).

Coding this may be a bit of a pain, but the simplest way is to mark the points on the boundary, and then have a function that tests if a point lies inside the convex hull of the marked points or not.

Comment: "Whenever you add a new point, test to see if it lies in the interior of this polytope or not. If so, the max distance is preserved. If not, then it may have changed."

Is this true? For a simple counterexample, let's say you have 12 points arranged in a circle in 2D. If you add a new point at the center, the max distance will have increased.

Comment: @Kevin: Given a set of points, the maximum distance between any two of them is the diameter of the convex hull of the points. My assertion follows from this fact.

Comment: You're right, and my simple example actually illustrates as much. Oops, thanks.

Comment: +1:  Though I don't think this will help for the minimum distance.

Comment: @Don: Quite correct on that. However, you can actually compute the dual if you want the minimum distance, but that's probably getting too heavy on the math and definitely computationally intensive.

Comment: To make sure I understand this conceptually:  Given a set of points, if you compute the Convex Hull, then the diameter of the hull is the maximal distance?  So once I have the hull computed, I can iterate the collection of points on the hull, and check each one against each other one, and save the maximum distance result.  So the point of the hull, in this case, is to cut down on the number of points that must be iterated in order to search for the maximum, not to prevent you from needing to search for the maximum via some property of the polygon itself?

Comment: @GWLlosa: Yes, you have it. This idea allows you to track the minimum amount of information (boundary points of the convex hull) to determine if a new maximum exists and, if so, what it is.

Comment: @GWLlosa: you actually do not need (at least in 2D) to iterate through **every** pair of points in the convex hull. It's possible to cut down the complexity to a function that is linear in the number of points using [rotating caliphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers).

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using a convex hull (as suggested in another answer) can you use a Delaunay triangulation??

**Min distance:**

To calculate the minimum distance from a node to any other in the set you should only need to check the immediate neighbours of the node, i.e. the ones connected to it by an edge in the triangulation.

So if a new node is inserted, update the triangulation, find the neighbours of the new node and any other nodes that were "involved" in the update, compute the distances for all nodes in this local "updated" set and check whether a new minimum was found. Similarly, if an existing node is deleted, again update the triangulation and recompute the distances for all nodes "involved".

There are a class of so-called "incremental" algorithms that can be used to build Delaunay triangulations that only require local modifications of the overall triangulation when inserting/deleting new nodes, so this is the type of approach I'd suggest for frequent insertions/deletions.

**Max distance:**

As suggested in the convex hull style answer, you would only need to recompute the distances between boundary nodes if a new node was added outside of the existing triangulation or if an existing boundary node was deleted.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not at all sure this is best, but it's the best I can think of right now.

Save the max together with a set of pairs of points at that distance.  (The max is not necessarily unique.)

Same of course for the min.

- When you add a point, compute the new point's distance to all other points, and replace your saved max and min together with its corresponding set of endpoint pairs if the new point participates in a better max or min, or update the set of endpoints if it matches the current best.
- When you remove a point, check whether that clears an entire remembered minimum or maximum enpoint set.  If not, you need do nothing.  But if it is, I think you'll need to recompute everything.

For the maximum computation, I believe PengOne's suggestion can tell you if you can skip the computation entirely.